# How does DataWriter's StoreAsync work under StreamSocket?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-store-apps, socketstream

I am creating socket client (TCP) in Windows Store (8\Metro\RT) app and I am trying to send data using this code:

```
await _socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(ipAddress), port);
_dataWriter = new DataWriter(_socket.OutputStream);
_dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
await _dataWriter.StoreAsync();
//Does execution in this line mean that bytes were sent 
//and TCP packet acknowledge has been received?
```

so the question is in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The completion of a write operation only means that the data has been copied to an OS buffer.

There is no way to be notified when you get a TCP ACK for the data; however, if you do *not* get one (after the built-in TCP retries), then the *next* operation you do on the socket will result in an error.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much.

Comment: @TimBertalot: `FlushAsync` will flush the `Stream` buffer, sending the bytes to the network layer. It does not send them over the network, and also will not wait for an `ACK`.